# Error in Rails Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have installed [RailsBestPractices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) by `gem install rails_best_practices` and then I went to a Rails project home directory, when I want to execute it I get this:

```
$ rails_best_practices -g
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rails_best_practices-1.4.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-20 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails_best_practices (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails_best_practices:18
```

What is wrong? and How can I fix it?

This issue was alse reported in [developer's code repository](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices/issues/79).
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the project:

$ rails_best_practices .